# Run Puppeteer in IBM Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, ibm-cloud, puppeteer, ibm-cloud-functions

I deployed Typescript code to run Puppeteer in IBM Cloud Functions.  It seems to be hanging when executing this code
`await page.goto(path, {timeout: 0})`

Without `{timeout: 0}`,
it will throw "TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded"

I have tried to configure TypeScript to use latest ecma version ("target": "es2018") as suggested here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

Also tried
`` await page.evaluate(`(async() => { console.log('1'); })()`); ``

But no luck.  Any idea how I can resolve this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around some more, I figured out that it was this line

`await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

that is causing it to hang.